# I can't add database in inbound data from salt method in php

Tags: php, insert-into

I have a problem as I mentioned this title.
I want to add named tbl_users in my database.
My tables column is user_name, password ans salt.
I have a Hash class.

```
class Hash {
    public static function create($string, $salt = '') {
        return hash('haval256,4',$string.$salt);
    }

    public static function salt($length = 32) {
        if(function_exists('random_bytes'))
            return random_bytes($length);
        else
            return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
    }

    public static function unique() {
        return self::create(uniqid());
    }
}
```

I am creating $salt variable for salt column by Hash::salt.
But, when I was added $salt variable value in salt column, it can't add this value.

```
$salt  = Hash::salt();
$pass  = Hash::create('123456',$salt);
$query = Connection::getInstance()->getConnection("INSERT INTO tbl_user SET user_name='BlaBlaBla' password='$pass', salt='$salt'");
```

But, I can add random values ('2345234',fgsdffs' like that).
I can't solve this. I'm waiting for your help. By the way I am knowing my english is weak. I'am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma before the password=.

Note I can really upset you by setting my password to 'xx''; drop table tbl_user;'

Comment: Thank you James Anderson. But I remembered a comma when I was wrote in here. Normally there are a comma before the password.Also I was used prepared statements in mysqli.